# How to extract all text in front of the '@' character in a string

Tags: php, string, replace, trim

how to remove a string starting from '@'?

for example admin@admin.com,  i want to remove the string starting from @ so it becomes 'admin' only.
just like in twitter..i read about str replace and trim but i think theres other way to do it?

```
$email = 'admin@admin.com';

echo substr_replace($email, ?, ?) ; this i cant do
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to replace the remainder, you can just *cut out until* the searched character. In this case it's very easy with [strtok](http://php.net/strtok):

```
 $name = strtok($email, "@");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this function: [strstr](http://php.net/function.strstr):

```
$start = strstr($email, '@', true);
```

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
substr($email, 0, strpos($email, '@'));
```

Answer (score 3):

`strtok()` is the best, but as an alternative...

```
$name = strstr($email, '@', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$email = 'admin@admin.com';
list($Lastpart,$Firstpart) = explode("@",$email); 

echo $Firstpart; //before @ sign
echo $Lastpart;  //after @ sign
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$email = explode("@", $email);

$name = $email[0];
```

Comment: If no error checking, you could use `list($name) = explode("@", $email)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$email = 'admin@admin.com';
$aEmail= explode('@',$email);
echo $aEmail[0];
```