# How to select start of a string until a :

Tags: php

I have this string:

467:some-text-here-1786

How can I select only the first numerical value before the ":" ?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [get number in front of 'underscore' with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220998/get-number-in-front-of-underscore-with-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return the portion of a string before the first occurence of a character in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766301/return-the-portion-of-a-string-before-the-first-occurrence-of-a-character-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract all text in front of @ in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273679/how-to-extract-all-text-in-front-of-the-character-in-a-string)

Comment: more http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=string+before+character

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simple:

```
list($var) = explode(":",$input);
```

or

```
$tmp = explode(":",$input);
$var = array_shift($tmp);
```

or (as pointed out by PhpMyCoder)

```
$tmp = current(explode(":",$input));
```

Comment: You could also use `reset()` instead of `array_shift()`.

Comment: Your use of array_shift() will fail, because it expects argument 1 to be a reference. You need to use a temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '467:some-text-here-1786';
$var = (int)$string;
```

Since you're extracting a number, this is enough :)
For an explanation of why this works, check the official PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

It's also really fast and really safe: you are sure you get a number.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = "467:some-text-here-1786";
$a = explode(":", $a);
$a = $a[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to do this:

```
$length = strpos($string, ':') + 1;
$number = substr($string, 0, $length);
```